# How to get cv2 running on python3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, opencv

I'm currently trying to get the cv2 library on python so I could play some videos using python. Whenever I try to install cv2 from pycharm I get this error:

```
Collecting cv2

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cv2
```

I looked around and read that I should install`opencv-python` using pip, and I did, but pycharm still does not recognise cv2.

Comment: It's often the case that multiple Python versions will be installed on a system, so you may have installed it to a different Python installation that what PyCharm is using. Try importing it after launching `python` at the command line. Also have you tried installing it using the PyCharm package installer? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: @PeterGibson I only have python 3.6 on my system, the error I'm showing is from the pycharm package installer.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me here. I just downloaded PyCharm 2018.1, created a new project using Python 3.6 and virtualenv, then navigated to the project settings and installed `opencv-python` using the PyCharm package manager

[image: Python Interpreter settings]

[image: opencv-python package]

I then had to restart the python console in PyCharm and I could successfully `import cv2`.

Comment: I completely removed python and pycharm from my system and reinstalled them and it worked. I don't understand how but thank you!